# Mid 2012 Macbook Air Black Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, display, safe-mode

Turned on my Macbook Air this morning and was greeted with a black screen, I could vaguely make out the login screen but when I entered my password the screen went completely black.  I tried restarting and booting into safe mode all to no avail.  I guess this also means I can't run Apple Hardware Test to see if that shows anything.  I've got it connected to an external display at the minute which is working fine.

Is there anything else I can try to fix the issue from my side before taking it to see a genius.

Cheers!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your backlight has broken.  The LCD screen needs to be lit from behind before the screen contents are more than vaguely visible.  If you boot the machine again, and shine a bright torch from the front, you should be able to see your usual screen layout for login etc, but obviously everything is going to be very very dull.  If this is the case, then you can get that fixed with relative ease at various repair centres or through a slew of online guides.

Sometimes on older hardware it's not the backlight that's gone, but instead the tiny *starter/transformer* that is required to kick a backlight into life, although this type of method isn't used on modern LED backlit screens like your Macbook